# how to pass json encode data to a form

Tags: php, json, laravel

```
function PrintMembers(){
    var url = '/PrintMList';
    var MDataList = $('#MDataList').val();      
    var form = $('<form action="' + url + '" method="post" id="search" target="_blank">' +
        '@csrf'+
        '<input type="text" name="MDataList" value="' + MDataList + '" />' +                                    
        '<input type="text" name="Action" value="'+Action+'" />' +              
        '</form>');
        $('body').append(form);
        $("#search").submit();      
}
```

in the PrintMList page, the array is empty when i print_r the MDataList in controller as below:

```
$var = $request->input('MDataList');
print_r($var);
```

Comment: Your Question is not clearly Understandable, Please describe more

Comment: is something wrong with my coding?when i print_r($var), no array data display

Comment: You can use ajax when submitting a form.

Comment: You put text in notepad, call it json but it's not even that, take a picture it, put it in a 3rd party site and then put link to here? How about just copy the text and paste it into your question? That way if someone wants to test your code, they also have it

Comment: i tried put the json output here earlier but it doesnt show when i post. thts why i had to put in image. how do i paste the json here

Comment: can see the codes here?<input type="text"  name="MDataList" id="MDataList" style="visibility:hidden" value="{&quot;1&quot;:{&quot;QrCode&quot;:&quot;&lt;img src=\&quot;..\/storage\/qr\/temp\/748375767cc85b078b2af0e49ee6f398.png\&quot; \/&gt;&quot;,&quot;SCode&quot;:&quot;0351952&quot;,&quot;SName&quot;:&quot;คุณบุญเลิศ  แสงทอง&quot;},&quot;2&quot;:{&quot;QrCode&quot;:&quot;&lt;img src=\&quot;..\/storage\/qr\/temp\/3fb0bda72c886c9af6ecf8280a9eca88.png\&quot; \/&gt;&quot;,&quot;SCode&quot;:&quot;0054199&quot;,&quot;SName&quot;:&quot;คุณมะลิ  อรพันธ์&quot;}}" >

Answer (score 0):

You can use Developer tools to check it after you append form to body

```
$('body').append(form); //go check after executed this
```

Your can find your form above 
[image]

Comment: i dont think can see right..since it is in jaavscript

Comment: this is my json array looks like https://1.bp.blogspot.com/-YyQp5eZiQus/YBuZcIndIfI/AAAAAAAAGoM/0aMoPZjGAdgOTsgFKX2AeyIteQzaLHC4QCLcBGAsYHQ/s16000/json.jpg

Comment: you have to make sure your form is made correctly, and ensure the process  passing data to the server is work correctly, because you said print_r($var); is empty maybe you can try print_r($request->all());

Comment: i dont think is the way i print is wrong. i think the way i pass the value in the form